# Is current record Id accessible before record has been saved?

Tags: id, record

I have created a Skuid page that overlays `Contact` record pages. There is a "New" button which creates a new `Task`record. on load of this new `Task` record, I wish for a `TaskRelation` record to be created and prepopulated with the associated `Contact` record.

To do this I am going to need the `Id` from the `Task` record and populate the `TaskRelation` record. Is it possible for me to get the `Id` from the new `Task` record before it has been saved? Or is the `Task` Id generated on save?

Use case: This is so the user knows the `Contact` has automatically been added associated with the `Task`

Comment: Why not write a trigger on Task on insert  that will create TaskRelation for you automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the Id of an object before it has been inserted.
  Only after the record is saved you can get it's Id.

I have not clear why you need the `TaskRelation` object to be created, but if you want to relate the `Task` record with the `Contact` record you can use the `WhoId` field of Task sObject to relate with Contact record.

Hope this solves what you are looking for.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/89455)

Comment: Thanks for noticing, wrote on a rush :-)  just updated the answer

Comment: Hi @Enrik. TaskRelatio allows you to assign same task to group of people, where as whoId allows you to assign a single entity.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal yeah I got it, but it is not clearly specified on the question that is needed to assign to a group of people

Comment: TaskRelation is only used for the same reason.. He's keen on using TaskRelation implies the architecture preference already made.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal ok then a trigger will solve the case, as you have mentioned above